# Expository Papers on Extenders

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, large-cardinals

Extenders are discussed in many set theory text books. Here I am looking for some expository "papers" which are focused on this subject and its connection with forcing and large cardinals. More generally I would like to know:

> What is the best reference to learn about extenders? Feel free to use your personal experience about the "best" reference for extenders.

Comment: Rather than a rigorous presentation, I would like to see an intuitive presentation of extenders. The definition is just so long and mysterious!

Comment: @William I edited the unnecessary definition.

Comment: There is an answer by Andres Caicedo in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201279/intuition-behind-extenders that may be helpful. There is no suggested reference though.

Comment: @William It is nice. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Sit in a [mini]course given by Magidor on the topic. He's a wonderful teacher. That's how I learn about large cardinals half the time.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Is there any lecture notes of Magidor's courses?

Comment: Not that I can recall, and none include extenders though. (This might be coming up next year, though, but it's remains to be seen.)

Comment: Check the chapter on determinacy in L(R) by Itay Neeman in the handbook of set theory. It contains a nice introduction to (short) extenders and iteration trees. This is how I learned the subject (well, it was accompanied by Magidor's lectures ;)).

Comment: @Haim: When did we talk about extender? I might be forgetting something, but I don't recall extenders. To my knowledge, I learned about extenders in the Friday seminar, more or less.

Comment: Oh, Asaf, look what alcohol and sleep deprivation have done to your memory. :p Two years ago, he gave an unofficial course on the proof of projective determinacy from large cardinals (accompanying the second half of his descriptive set theory course). Though if I remember correctly, there were only two students (including me) who stayed until he finished the proof.

Comment: @Haim: It's not alcohol and sleep deprivation. It's just entropy. And the last three or four lectures of the semester were already into the exams in Ben-Gurion so I couldn't attend. So it makes sense that I wasn't there to remember this from the beginning.