# Where does the term "mouse" (in set theory) come from?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

Does the term mouse stand for "Model Of Universe with Sequences of Extenders" or perhaps mice stands for "Model Including Cardinal Extensions"?

---

A quick review:

[Gödel's L-universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) is a core model for ZF, defined via transfinite induction as follows:

- $L_0 := \emptyset$
- $L_{\alpha + 1} := Def(L_\alpha)$
- $L_\beta := \bigcup \{ L_\alpha | \alpha < \beta \}$ ($\alpha$ precedes $\beta$)

If we wish to examine a natural inner model for a strong cardinal, we add extender sequences (i.e., sequences of compatible ultrafilters) to our universe so that we can deal with large cardinals.  The universe $L$ with this additional axiom of [extender](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201279/intuition-behind-extenders) sequences is denoted $L[E]$.

It's my understanding that we call the structure $L_\alpha [E]$ a mouse if our $E$ is in some way canonical (a "coherent/good extender sequence"). ($L_\alpha[E]$ without this added condition of "canonicality" is called a "premouse").

Apologies if the above is off-kilter, I've likely got some of the model-theoretic vocabulary mixed-up.

Comment: As far as I know it is something of a running joke that Jensen keeps changing his story about how he chose the name mouse. It definitely isn't some sort of acronym. I think the most widely accepted version is that he deemed the concept so important that he wanted a completely new term for it, without any existing mathematical connotations.

Comment: At the time, we were told that the name was picked, more or less, at random.

Comment: I have been told by several people that it was as a result of a typo of `nice'. Incidentally, I always thought that the key something being a mouse was that you could iterate the ultrapower using the extender sequence through the ordinals whilst keeping the ultrapower well-founded. I'm a relative newbie to this too though!

Comment: The OP is probably aware of this paper, but for readers who may not be, I recommend Schimmerling's paper [The ABCs of mice](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687795?seq=1) as a relatively readable introduction to the topic.

Comment: Perhaps $\text{mouse}_\text{set}=\text{model of ZF}$ in the same way that $\text{mouse}_\text{biology}=\text{model for experiments}$...

Comment: The story I remember hearing (at CMU in the oughties, probably from either James Cummings or Ernest Schimmerling) is similar to @NeilBarton’s: that Jensen dictated to a note-taker or typist “we call models with such-and-such properties nice”, the not-taker either misheard or mis-typed, and Jensen decided he liked the typo enough to keep it…